# IIS Express vs IIS Site and Access Denied Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Trying to migrate a legacy .net site from a SharePoint 2010 farm to SharePoint 2016.  *Simple IIS site that has one page for testing.*

Run the site in IIS Express and everything works.  Run the same site in IIS and I receive an Access Denied error.

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(Function() doSP(hURL))

  Function doSP(hURL As String)
                    Using hSite As New SPSite(hURL)
                        Using hWeb As SPWeb = hSite.OpenWeb()
                            Dim listItems As SPListItemCollection = hWeb.Lists("testx").Items
                            Dim item As SPListItem = listItems.Add()
                            item("Title") = "test1"
                            item.Update()
                        End Using
                    End Using
  End Function
```

App pool is running as my account and I also tried using the farm account.
My account is granted Full Control to the SharePoint web app via User Policy.  Also granted my account Site Collection Admin permissions.

**Full error:**
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: To be clear, this is an IIS web site running outside SharePoint on the WFE?I don't think I would use RunWithElevatedPrivileges in that context. What security context does your IIS app normally run under?

Comment: No, the site runs on one of my SP WFE boxes.  App pool runs under a service account with explicit permissions to one web app.  ...  I was asked to get it running, then we are moving the site to a dedicated app server outside the SP farm.

Comment: This code will not run outside the farm.

Comment: Yep, plan on modernizing the site to use web services calls and move away from using the server object model.

Answer (score 0):

try using `AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` before the update and `AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;` after the update.

also like to note its very clear on IIS 8 the pitfalls of running code express (admin level) vs IIS (restricted permission)

> **Security Context for IIS Express**
>
> ---
>
> An important difference between the development servers in Visual
>   Studio and IIS is the security context in which the servers run your
>   ASP.NET pages. This difference can be a source of problems when you
>   deploy a web site or web application to run on IIS.
>
> **When you run a page using IIS Express, the page runs in the context of
>   your current user account. For example, if you are running as an
>   administrator-level user, a page running in IIS Express will have
>   administrator-level privileges. In contrast, in IIS 7 and IIS 8,
>   ASP.NET runs as an account that has limited privileges by default**. For
>   more information, see Application Pool Identities on the IIS.net web
>   site.
>
> If you are simply reading and running the code in ASP.NET pages, this
>   difference is not very important. However, the different security
>   contexts for the two web servers can affect your testing in several
>   ways:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx

if the above code doesn't work then look at impersonation rather than elevation.

Comment: Thank you for the info, ali.  I failed to include AllowUnsafeUpdates is in my code example, but I am using it.  Currently looking at rewriting the site using CSOM.